# How is a reduction in the number of molecules associated with a decrease in Entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics

How is a reduction in the number of molecules associated with a decrease in Entropy? For example, stoichiometric equations like $\ce{H2 + O -> H2O}$ are enthalpy driven if I am correct. But it also implies that entropy is decreasing because the system is becoming "more orderly." Is this intuition correct?

Comment: That is true though the magnitude does depend on what phase are the products. If you somehow use solid reactants to produce a product which is gas, the entropy increases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpreting [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) as "disorder", which comes from thermodynamics applications, is only one way to interpret entropy. Entropy can also be described [according to statistical mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Statistical_mechanics) as the statistical distribution of possible degenerate microstates:

$$S=k_B \ln\Omega$$

where $k_B$ is [Boltzman's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant) and $\Omega$ is the number of microstates. Thus it is a measure of uncertainty. The more equivalent/degenerate microstates there are, the less likely we know exactly which one of them the system is in, and thus, the higher the entropy. This probabilistic interpretation provides a more intuitive and satisfactory understanding of the relationship between number of molecules and entropy of the system.

> A decrease in the number of molecules leads to a decrease in the total number of degenerate microstates, which leads to a decrease in entropy. There are more degenerate ways to distribute N objects in M spaces than there are degenerate ways to distribute (N-1) objects in M spaces.

Let's look at a very simple example, in which we have three molecules $\ce{2H2 + O2}$ in a container with room for four molecules. How many ways can we fill four spaces with these three molecules? There are four spaces in which we could put the $\ce{O2}$ molecule:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\ce{O2} & ... \\ 
... & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
... & \ce{O2} \\ 
... & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
... & ... \\ 
\ce{O2} & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
... & ... \\ 
... & \ce{O2} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How many ways can we put two $\ce{H2}$ molecules in one of these arrangements? In order to answer this, we need to temporarily distinguish one $\ce{H2}$ from the other $\ce{H2^{\circ}}$ (or to distinguish the one we place first from the one we place second) in order to generate all of the degenerate states.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\ce{O2} & \ce{H2} \\ 
\ce{H2^{\circ}} & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\ce{O2} & \ce{H2} \\ 
... & \ce{H2^{\circ}} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\ce{O2} & \ce{H2^{\circ}} \\ 
\ce{H2} & ... \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\ce{O2} & ... \\ 
\ce{H2} & \ce{H2^{\circ}} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\ce{O2} & \ce{H2^{\circ}} \\ 
... & \ce{H2} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\ce{O2} & ... \\ 
\ce{H2^{\circ}} & \ce{H2} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

There are six arrangements of two $\ce{H2}$ molecules for each location of $\ce{O2}$ for a total of $\Omega=24$ arrangements. The entropy $S=k_B\ln(24)=4.39\times10^{-23}) \frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}}$. Note that this happened to be $\Omega=4\times3\times2=12$, or 4 ways of placing the first molecule, 3 ways of placing the second, and two ways of placing the third. We will use this shortcut next time we do this.

Now, let us run the reaction, converting hydrogen and oxygen to water.

$$\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O}$$

And let us repeat the exercise. How many ways can we fit two $\ce{H2O}$ molecules in four spots? There are 4 ways to place the first one, and 3 ways to place the second for each of those 4 placements of the first. Thus, $\Omega=4\times3=12$ and the entropy is $S=k_B\ln(12)=3.43\times10^{-23}) \frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}}$.

> Note that there is a subtle flaw in my explanation. The molecules themselves have an intrinsic entropy hidden in their structures as well. According to [this site](http://chemed.chem.wisc.edu/chempaths/GenChem-Textbook/Standard-Molar-Entropies-984.html) the standard molar entropies of $\ce{O2},\ \ce{H2},$ and $\ce{H2O}$ are (in$\frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}\cdot\text{mol}}$) 205.1, 130.7, and 188.8, respectively. Thus, we have an entropy change of reaction:

$$\Delta_rS^\circ=\sum S^\circ_{products} - \sum S^\circ_{reactants}$$ $$ \Delta_rS^\circ =\left(2\times188.8 - (205.1+2\times130.7)\right)\frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}\cdot\text{mol}}=-40\frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}\cdot\text{mol}}$$

By comparing standard entropies, we also get a decrease in entropy. Standard entropies are easier to work with because we are frequently working on the molar scale. If we changed our simplified example to be moles of $\ce{H2}, \ \ce{O2},$ and $\ce{H2O}$, in 4 moles of spaces we would have the original number of microstates be:

$$\Omega=(4N_A)(4N_A-1)(4N_A-2)=64N_A^3-48N_A^2+8N_A$$

When you plug in $N_A=6.022\times10^{23}$, all but the most staunch calculators and computer programs are going to give up. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284%2a6.022e23%29%284%2a6.022e23-1%29%284%2a6.022e23-2%29) can do it because it does so symbolically, and we get

$$\Omega=1.398\times10^{73}$$

$$S=8.314\frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}\cdot\text{mol}}\ln(1.398\times10^{73})=1.400\times10^3\frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}\cdot\text{mol}}$$

(At the molar scale we replace $K_B$ with $R$, the ideal as constant.)

Another apparent weakness of the statistical approach is that it assumes no phase change. As F'x mentioned, there is an entropy change associated with a phase change. Roughly, the number of available spaces increases or decreases.

Answer (score 2):

**Gases have much larger molar entropy than liquids and solids**, owing to the contribution of translational entropy (gas molecules have much less hindered translational movement than molecules in liquids or solids). Thus, **for a reaction that diminishes the total number of gas molecules, you can expect to have $\Delta_r S° < 0$**.

This is also true to some extent with other phases, as long as all reactants and products are in the same phase. But, if you have a reaction with some products or reactants in the gas phase, those will determine the sign of the molar reaction entropy.